# R How to estimate csv file size prior to writing it to disk

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, diskspace

Is there any way in R to estimate the file size of a csv file prior to actually writing it to disk via `write.csv` or `readr::write_csv`? I would like to implement a warning if the user accidentially tries to write huge files to disk in a function.

There seems to be some relationship between memory footprint of a dataframe (`object.size`) and the size on disk, with the latter being considerably larger. However, the larger the object in memory, the smaller the difference. Also, there might be differences related to the structure of the dataframe.

I do not want to force people to download large amounts of data, so please excuse the lack of an reproducible example.

Comment: For warning, you can simply compare the memory footprint of the object inside R. If it is large than a threshold, you can issue warning.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://data.nozav.org/posts/2016/02/compression_benchmark.html) relevant: on object size vs file size with various file formats. For the object size used in the benchmark, the difference to the csv file was 'rather large' (343.3 MB vs 2885 MB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of @lukeA, I came up with the following with good results for the estimated filesize:

```
csv_write <- function(df = idata, filename){
  if(interactive){
    if(dim(df)[1] > 10^4){
      divisor <- 1000
      if(dim(df)[1] > 10^5){
        divisor <- 10000
      }

      df_sample <- sample_n(df, size = dim(df)[1] %/% divisor)

      test <- paste(capture.output(write.csv(df_sample)), collapse="\n")

      cat("Writing", capture.output(print(object.size(test)*divisor,
                                          units="auto")), "to disk. \n")
    }
  }

  write_csv(df, path = filename)
}
```

One remaining problem is that I need to use `write.csv`instead of `readr::write_csv` to compute the approximate output size, since `readr::write_csv` requires a `path` argument. The alternative `readr::format_csv`, which does not require a path, underestimates the filesize considerably (e.g. 2.7 Gb estimated vs. 3.3 Gb on disk).

Comment: Good idea to think of `readr` - try `readr::format_csv(USArrests)`, which does not require a path argument.

Comment: Yes, but like I wrote, using ```read::format_csv()```gets the estimated file size quite a bit wrong @lukaA

Answer (score 7):

Here's one idea

```
to <- paste(capture.output(write.csv(USArrests)), collapse="\n")
write.csv(USArrests, tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
file.info(tf)$size
# [1] 1438
print(object.size(to), units="b")
# 1480 bytes
```

Comment: Not sure if I get this right, but this does actually write to disk, or?

Comment: He is writing to (1) memory and (2) file and showing that they are the same size. I think for the purposes of your estimate, you could write the first twenty records to memory (or a temporary file) and then estimate by the ratio to total lines to twenty.

Comment: Like @A.Webb said: I'm (1) writing a virtual csv file to memory and get its size. Then (2) I write another csv to disc to compare the sizes, which are similar - at least for the `USArrests` dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `object.size` method:

```
 object.size(m) # where m is your data object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following three functions to calculate the exact size of the file that will be written by `write.table()`, `write.csv()`, and `write.csv2()`, respectively, without having to produce the entire byte stream at once, either in memory or on disk:

```
size.write.table <- function(x,...) {
    x <- as.data.frame(x); ## write.table() coerces to data.frame
    args <- list(...);
    defaults <- formals(write.table);
    ## get write specs as locals
    for (name in names(defaults)[-1])
        assign(name,if (is.null(args[[name]])) defaults[[name]] else args[[name]]);
    ## normalize quote arg to logical, quoteIndexes as columns to quote
    ## note: regardless of qmethod, does not touch characters other than double-quote, and only adds one byte per embedded double-quote for either qmethod
    quoteIndexesGiven <- F; ## assumption
    if (is.logical(quote) && quote) {
        quoteIndexes <- seq_along(x);
    } else if (is.numeric(quote)) {
        quoteIndexes <- quote;
        quote <- T;
        quoteIndexesGiven <- T;
    }; ## end if
    ## normalize col.names arg to logical T/F, colNames as actual column names
    emptyColNameForRowNames <- F; ## assumption
    if (is.logical(col.names)) {
        if (is.na(col.names)) {
            emptyColNameForRowNames <- T;
            col.names <- T;
        }; ## end if
        if (col.names) colNames <- names(x);
    } else {
        colNames <- as.character(col.names);
        col.names <- T;
    }; ## end if
    ## normalize row.names arg to logical, rowNames as actual row names
    if (is.logical(row.names)) {
        if (row.names) rowNames <- rownames(x);
    } else {
        rowNames <- as.character(row.names);
        row.names <- T;
    }; ## end if (else must be F)
    ## start building up file size
    size <- 0L;
    ## 1: column header
    if (col.names) {
        ## special case for zero columns: write.table() behaves as if there's one empty-string column name, weirdly
        if (ncol(x)==0L) {
            if (quote) size <- size + 2L;
        } else {
            if (emptyColNameForRowNames) {
                if (quote) size <- size + 2L; ## two double-quotes
                size <- size + nchar(sep,'bytes'); ## separator
            }; ## end if
            size <- size + sum(nchar(colNames,'bytes')); ## names (note: NA works with this; nchar() returns 2)
            if (quote) size <- size + ncol(x)*2L + sum(do.call(c,gregexpr(perl=T,'"',colNames[quoteIndexes]))>0L); ## quotes and escapes
            size <- size + nchar(sep,'bytes')*(ncol(x)-1L); ## separators
        }; ## end if
        size <- size + nchar(eol,'bytes'); ## eol; applies to both zero-columns special case and otherwise
    }; ## end if
    ## 2: row names
    if (row.names) {
        ## note: missing values are not allowed in row names
        size <- size + sum(nchar(rowNames,'bytes')); ## names
        size <- size + nchar(sep,'bytes')*nrow(x); ## separator (note: always present after row names, even for zero-column data.frame)
        if (quote) size <- size + nrow(x)*2L + sum(do.call(c,gregexpr(perl=T,'"',rowNames))>0L); ## quotes and escapes (can ignore quoteIndexes, since row names are always quoted if any column is quoted)
    }; ## end if
    ## 3: column content
    for (ci in seq_along(x)) {
        ## calc depends on class
        cl <- class(x[[ci]]);
        ## normalize date/time classes
        if (identical(cl,c('POSIXct','POSIXt')) || identical(cl,c('POSIXlt','POSIXt')))
            cl <- 'POSIXt';
        ## branch on normalized class
        ## note: can't write list type to file, so don't bother supporting list columns
        if (length(cl)==1L && cl=='raw') {
            size <- size + nrow(x)*2L;
            ## note: cannot have raw NAs
        } else { ## remaining types can have NAs
            size <- size + sum(is.na(x[[ci]]))*nchar(na,'bytes'); ## NAs
            if (length(cl)==1L && cl=='logical') {
                size <- size + sum((5:4)[na.omit(x[[ci]])+1L]); ## non-NAs
            } else if (length(cl)==1L && cl%in%c('integer','numeric','complex','ts')) {
                size <- size + sum(nchar(as.character(na.omit(x[[ci]])),'bytes')); ## non-NAs
            } else if (length(cl)==1L && cl%in%c('character','factor')) {
                size <- size + sum(nchar(as.character(na.omit(x[[ci]])),'bytes')); ## non-NAs, values -- as.character() required for factors to work
                if (quote && ci%in%quoteIndexes) size <- size + sum(!is.na(x[[ci]]))*2L + sum(do.call(c,gregexpr(perl=T,'"',na.omit(x[[ci]])))>0L); ## quotes and escapes
            } else if (length(cl)==1L && cl=='POSIXt') {
                size <- size + sum(nchar(as.character(na.omit(x[[ci]])),'bytes')); ## non-NAs
                ## special case for POSIXt: only quoted if explicitly specified by index in quote arg
                if (quoteIndexesGiven && ci%in%quoteIndexes) size <- size + sum(!is.na(x[[ci]]))*2L; ## quotes (can't be any escapes)
            } else {
                stop(sprintf('unsupported class(es) %s.',paste(collapse=',',cl)));
            }; ## end if
        }; ## end if
    }; ## end for
    ## 4: separators between columns
    size <- size + nchar(sep,'bytes')*(ncol(x)-1L)*nrow(x);
    ## 5: eols
    size <- size + nchar(eol,'bytes')*nrow(x);
    size;
}; ## end size.write.table()
## note: documentation should say "col.names to NA if row.names = TRUE (the default) or given as a character vector" for csv functions
size.write.csv <- function(x,...) do.call(size.write.table,c(list(x),sep=',',dec='.',qmethod='double',col.names={ row.names <- list(...)$row.names; if (!identical(F,row.names)) NA else T; },list(...)));
size.write.csv2 <- function(x,...) do.call(size.write.table,c(list(x),sep=';',dec=',',qmethod='double',col.names={ row.names <- list(...)$row.names; if (!identical(F,row.names)) NA else T; },list(...)));
```

---

Here are some tests demonstrating correctness:

```
size.write.func.test.impl <- function(funcName,x,...,tf='/tmp/size.write.func.test.impl.txt') {
    writeFunc <- match.fun(funcName);
    sizeFunc <- match.fun(paste0('size.',funcName));
    writeFunc(x,tf,...);
    expected <- file.info(tf)$size;
    actual <- sizeFunc(x,tf,...);
    cat(sprintf('%s: %d %s %d\n',if (expected==actual) 'SUCCESS' else 'FAILURE',actual,if (expected==actual) '==' else '!=',expected));
}; ## end size.write.func.test.impl()
size.write.table.test <- function(...) size.write.func.test.impl('write.table',...);
size.write.csv.test <- function(...) size.write.func.test.impl('write.csv',...);
size.write.csv2.test <- function(...) size.write.func.test.impl('write.csv2',...);
size.all.test <- function(...) {
    size.write.table.test(...);
    size.write.csv.test(...);
    size.write.csv2.test(...);
}; ## end size.all.test()

size.all.test(data.frame(),quote=F);
## SUCCESS: 1 == 1
## SUCCESS: 1 == 1
## SUCCESS: 1 == 1
size.all.test(data.frame());
## SUCCESS: 3 == 3
## SUCCESS: 3 == 3
## SUCCESS: 3 == 3
size.all.test(data.frame(a=1:3));
## SUCCESS: 22 == 22
## SUCCESS: 25 == 25
## SUCCESS: 25 == 25
set.seed(1L);
df <- data.frame(raw=as.raw(0:255),logical=rep(c(F,T),len=256L),integer=0:255,double1=runif(256L),double2=runif(256L,-.Machine$double.xmax*0.5,.Machine$double.xmax*0.5),character=paste(sapply(0:255,intToUtf8),sample(c('','x','x"x','"x""x"'),256L,replace=T)),factor=factor(rep(letters,len=256L)),dtΩ=as.POSIXct('1970-01-01 00:00:00',tz='England/London'),stringsAsFactors=F);
for (ci in seq(2,ncol(df))) df[[ci]][sample(256L,10L)] <- NA;
head(df);
##   raw logical integer   double1        double2 character factor        dtΩ
## 1  00   FALSE       0 0.2655087 -4.535097e+307                a 1970-01-01
## 2  01    TRUE       1 0.3721239 -2.670418e+305  \001 x"x      b 1970-01-01
## 3  02   FALSE       2 0.5728534 -2.285466e+307  \002 x"x      c 1970-01-01
## 4  03    TRUE       3 0.9082078  7.814417e+307     \003       d 1970-01-01
## 5  04      NA       4 0.2016819  4.311961e+306  \004 x"x      e 1970-01-01
## 6  05    TRUE       5 0.8983897 -3.287178e+307  \005 x"x      f 1970-01-01
size.all.test(df);
## SUCCESS: 20634 == 20634
## SUCCESS: 20637 == 20637
## SUCCESS: 20637 == 20637
size.all.test(df,eol='zzz');
## SUCCESS: 21148 == 21148
## SUCCESS: 21151 == 21151
## SUCCESS: 21151 == 21151
size.all.test(df,sep='///'); ## csv incarnations take ownership of their overridden arguments
## SUCCESS: 24744 == 24744
## SUCCESS: 20637 == 20637
## SUCCESS: 20637 == 20637
## Warning messages:
## 1: In writeFunc(x, tf, ...) : attempt to set 'sep' ignored
## 2: In writeFunc(x, tf, ...) : attempt to set 'sep' ignored
size.all.test(df,quote=F);
## SUCCESS: 18807 == 18807
## SUCCESS: 18808 == 18808
## SUCCESS: 18808 == 18808
size.all.test(df,quote=seq(2L,ncol(df),by=2L));
## SUCCESS: 20634 == 20634
## SUCCESS: 20637 == 20637
## SUCCESS: 20637 == 20637
size.all.test(df,row.names=F);
## SUCCESS: 19206 == 19206
## SUCCESS: 19206 == 19206
## SUCCESS: 19206 == 19206
size.all.test(df,row.names=seq(1234,len=nrow(df)));
## SUCCESS: 20998 == 20998
## SUCCESS: 21001 == 21001
## SUCCESS: 21001 == 21001
size.all.test(df,na='blah');
## SUCCESS: 20774 == 20774
## SUCCESS: 20777 == 20777
## SUCCESS: 20777 == 20777
size.all.test(iris);
## SUCCESS: 4818 == 4818
## SUCCESS: 4821 == 4821
## SUCCESS: 4821 == 4821
size.all.test(USAccDeaths);
## SUCCESS: 724 == 724
## SUCCESS: 727 == 727
## SUCCESS: 727 == 727
size.all.test(USArrests);
## SUCCESS: 1384 == 1384
## SUCCESS: 1387 == 1387
## SUCCESS: 1387 == 1387
size.all.test(USArrests,eol='\r\n'); ## you're probably on Windows
## SUCCESS: 1435 == 1435
## SUCCESS: 1438 == 1438
## SUCCESS: 1438 == 1438
```